# How to return a list in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to write a simple function that returns a list, but I keep getting an error at last line of code (`return query.ToList()`). Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

This is the code.

Thanks.

```
List<POS2012.Models.Entities.Products> GetItemOrPack(String ProductId, bool Ischecked)
{
    using(var db = new POSContext())
    {
        var query = (from c in db.Product
                     where c.ProductId == ProductId
                     select new { c.PackCostPrice, c.PackSalePrice});

        return query.ToList();
    }              
}
```

Comment: We can neither see your screen, nor read your mind - you'll have to **post** that error (please: post the complete and exact error you're getting) - thank you

Comment: @marc_s: the error has been added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type you select in your query does not match the return type.

Try this, it will select the appropiate type in your query, so that the conversion `ToList()` is possible.

```
using(var db = new POSContext())
{
    var query = (from c in db.Product
                 where c.ProductId == ProductId
                 select new POS2012.Models.Entities.Products ()
                 { 
                      PackCostPrice = c.PackCostPrice, 
                      PackSalePrice = c.PackSalePrice
                 });

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Alternative:

```
using(var db = new POSContext())
{
    return (from c in db.Product
            where c.ProductId == ProductId
            select c).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your code is working perfectly but one question on this line of code PackCostPrice = c.PackCostPrice. Here why are you assigning c.PackCosePrice property to PackCosePrice, thanks.

Comment: @user3004110: I didn't realized the types where the same when I typed that. That's why I came up with the alternative. The alternative works because the return type is the same as the entity. The first option can be used if your return type is different from your entity and you'll need a mapping. You can `select new Foo() { a = c.PackCostPrice }` or whatever you like.

Comment: @user3004110: next time, try to post the exact error message as well. It helps others to find it with google ;-)

Comment: Iam facing an error on return query.ToList(); The error is following:- "The entity or complex type 'POS2012.Models.Products' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `select new { c.PackCostPrice, c.PackSalePrice})` is projecting the `Product` into an anonymous object.

Then, instead of returning `List<POS2012.Models.Entities.Products>` your're actually returning `List<#AnonymousType>`.

If you only need `PackCostPrice` and `PackSalePrice`, change the method accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your method return type instead of anonymous type:

```
    List<POS2012.Models.Entities.Products> GetItemOrPack(String ProductId, bool Ischecked)
            {
                using(var db = new POSContext())
                {
                    var query = (from c in db.Product
                                 where c.ProductId == ProductId
                                 select newPOS2012.Models.Entities.Products{ 
                       PackCostPrice = c.PackCostPrice, 
                       PackSalePrice = c.PackSalePrice});

                    return query.ToList();

                }

            }
```

Comment: That won't compile. `select newPOS2012.Models.Entities.Products{ c.PackCostPrice, c.PackSalePrice})` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: sorry, my mistake - fixed, thanks

Comment: Hello iam getting error on query.toList() The error is following:- The entity or complex type 'POS2012.Models.Products' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Answer (score 0):

Put `select new POS2012.Models.Entities.Products` instead of `select new`like below

```
        List<POS2012.Models.Entities.Products> GetItemOrPack(String ProductId, bool Ischecked)
    {
        using (var db = new POSContext())
        {
            var query = (from c in db.Product
                         where c.ProductId == ProductId
                         select new POS2012.Models.Entities.Products { c.PackCostPrice, c.PackSalePrice });

            return query.ToList();

        }

    }
```

Comment: I exactly write the same code but error is still comimg. What can be the other possibility? Thanks.